# Consuming SAP web service via .net

Tags: .net, xml, web-services, wsdl, uri

i am pretty new to web service so i am fighting with some strange behavior. After i have imported the WSDL xml file via VS2010 i get these unrecognized policy assertions. The WSDL file was created by the SAP team, so i am not sure what they exactly did.

When i am ignoring these commets an try to consume the web service i get this expections:
**The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; expected 'http'.**

I know that this errormessage means that i have a different transport logic as the URI defines, but i am not sure if i should do something about it or renew the WSDL file.

```
    <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
    <customBinding>
        <binding name="binding">
            <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style':    -->
            <!--    <wsdl:binding name='binding'>    -->
            <!--        <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/">..</saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer>    -->
            <!--        <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">..</sapattahnd:Enabled>    -->
            <mtomMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                messageVersion="Soap11WSAddressing10" maxBufferSize="65536"
                writeEncoding="utf-8">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </mtomMessageEncoding>
            <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="binding_SOAP12">
            <!--    WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'urn:sap-com:document:sap:soap:functions:mc-style':    -->
            <!--    <wsdl:binding name='binding_SOAP12'>    -->
            <!--        <saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer xmlns:saptrnbnd="http://www.sap.com/webas/710/soap/features/transportbinding/">..</saptrnbnd:OptimizedXMLTransfer>    -->
            <!--        <sapattahnd:Enabled xmlns:sapattahnd="http://www.sap.com/710/features/attachment/">..</sapattahnd:Enabled>    -->
            <mtomMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                messageVersion="Default" maxBufferSize="65536" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                    maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
            </mtomMessageEncoding>
            <httpsTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                useDefaultWebProxy="true" requireClientCertificate="false" />
        </binding>
    </customBinding>
</bindings>
<client>
    <endpoint address="http://{HOSTNAME}/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zicert_kunden_auslesen/010/005056a5007b1ee2a5da43a20303be2b/binding"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding" contract="ServiceReference.ZICERT_KUNDEN_AUSLESEN"
        name="binding" />
    <endpoint address="http://{HOSTNAME}/sap/bc/srt/rfc/sap/zicert_kunden_auslesen/010/005056a5007b1ee2a5da43a20303be2b/binding"
        binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="binding_SOAP12"
        contract="ServiceReference.ZICERT_KUNDEN_AUSLESEN" name="binding_SOAP12" />
</client>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Endpoint has the `http` scheme, but the binding only defines `httpsTransport`. You could try changing the binding to `httpTransport`, or see if your endpoints are available with the `https` protocol too.

Comment: Thanks. I have changed it to **httpTransport** and switched to the **authenticationScheme="Basic"** but now i am getting: **{"The server did not provide a meaningful reply; this might be caused by a contract mismatch, a premature session shutdown or an internal server error."}**

Answer (score 0):

Please try using `TransportCredentialOnly` as the security mode, which not requires HTTPS protocol (while you need to provide user name and password).

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="NewBinding">
      <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

You can set the user name and password in .NET code as below:

```
sapService.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "UserName";
sapService.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
```